# Is there a way to add customer Grid in product edit page?

Tags: magento-1.9, product, customer-grid

I m trying to add customer grid to magento admin product detail page.but it didn't display.I had googed and try but i can't find any resource for the same.Please some one can help to achieve this.

It would be great if someone can help on this topic.
[image]

Comment: can not understand what is the requirement,please explain briefly

Comment: have added image what i want to do in product edit page.

Answer (score 2):

Feedom ,

**Step1:** Create new tab using [Inchoo Blog](http://inchoo.net/magento/how-to-add-custom-product-relations-in-magento/).This block is help you to crate new tab in porduct tab.

**Step2:** According to your requirement you need to show an `subgrid which will show` list of customer which are placed this product.
You need to change code of class `Inchoo_CustomLinkedProducts_Model_Catalog_Product`

In

```
app/code/community/Inchoo/CustomLinkedProducts/Block/Adminhtml/Catalog/Product/Edit/Tab/Custom.php
```

Code :

```
$collection = Mage::getModel("sales/order_item")->getCollection()
  ->addFieldToFilter("product_id", $this->_getProduct()->getId());

$collection->getSelect()->join( array('sales_order'=>Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName('sales/order')),
        'main_table.order_id = sales_order.entity_id', array('sales_order.customer_id'));
$collection->getSelect()->where('customer_id IS NOT NULL');
```

More details will come shortly